# Where can I buy bulk DUPLO sized bricks?

Tags: duplo, lugbulk

I am working on a project where I need LOTS of basic DUPLO sized bricks and/or plates. I need only the simple sizes, 2x2 and 2x4 and possibly 2x6. I do not want any pieces with curves, slopes, decals, etc...

I do not even require them to be LEGO brand. It would be an added benefit if they were, but I really just need to cheapest way to find lots of these pieces.

I would like a source for NEW or LIKE NEW parts. I don't necessarily have to have new parts, but I don't want to mess around with ordering used parts that can have a wide variety of things wrong with them.

I have looked on Bricklink, as they have been an awesome resource for normal sized LEGO parts. However, there just doesn't seem to be much of a supply of DUPLO on there.

Any ideas where to look next?

Perhaps there is a Clone brand that I can order specific parts from?

Answer (score 4):

Duplo is less often stocked than normal LEGO, but [this (US) Bricklink store](http://www.bricklink.com/store.asp?p=jod27&itemID=85882075) seems to have quite some in stock. You might find other Bricklink stores in different parts of the world that have stock as well.

Another option is looking for the [10622 Duplo Large Creative Box](http://brickset.com/sets/10622-1/Large-Creative-Box), which was on Black Friday sale at Walmart recently. It can still be found on [Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B018DM4FDO) and [eBay](http://www.ebay.com/itm/LEGO-DUPLO-Large-Creative-Box-10622-BRAND-NEW-IN-SEALED-BOX-/111864725496), but contains many "other" kinds of bricks apart from your basic 2x4 and 2x2 bricks. Also, at ~$0.30 per brick (MSRP) this might not be your cheapest option - the Bricklink store I linked earlier has 2x2 bricks for as little as $0.12. Also check out last year's [10557 Duplo Creative Tower](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00BMKRG0E) - it has more pieces (200 vs 193) and sells for less on Amazon currently.

You can also find bulk lots of Duplo bricks on eBay, such as [this one](http://www.ebay.com/itm/Nice-lot-of-48-DUPLO-blocks-super-deal-/252231168728). Price with shipping is still ~$0.30 per brick.

EDIT: Two more options:

1) If you're in North America, go look up a second-hand baby/children's clothing store like Once Upon A Child. I went there today and found several sealed bags and boxes with Duplo blocks. Common price was ~$6 for a bag. It was difficult to see what was in each item, but this might get you something.

2) You can look at Mega Blocks - their large bricks don't interconnect with LEGO or Duplo, but depending on what you are trying to do that might not matter. You could always stack them sideways, or modify them, or even (yikes!) glue LEGO bricks on top to make a connection.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help. I also found a few options on Bricklink. But the best case appears to be similar to what you found, 20 pieces here and there. I will need a consistent reliable source of 50 - 100 of the exact same piece at a time. Regarding the boxed sets, there's just too many pieces I don't want in those sets. I'm fine with $.30 / piece, but not when I have to buy 100's of parts I don't want. There's gotta be a way to get the specific parts I want, even if it's from a Clone of some sort...

Comment: @Dustin Your best solution may be buying those boxes, then selling off the pieces you don't want. DUPLO doesn't really have clones. Even Megablok's similar product isn't a direct match.

Answer (score 4):

The official Lego site sells individual Duplo and Lego bricks, but they don't make it easy. For Lego it's not too hard, just Shop By Bricks, then Pick a Brick. For Duplo it's less obvious: hover over the Support tab, then click on Replacement parts, then Buy Bricks (for some reason they then ask how old you are; no Duplo to be sold to under 18's, like beer). You can then enter the Set number or Element/design number. I found the Element/design number by first searching the site for Duplo sets (Themes, Duplo), choosing a set and entering the Set number into the Set number bar, then getting the individual Design number for each part of the set I wanted. (Do they want us to buy the stuff or what?) I found the Design number for standard 4X2 Duplo bricks is 3011, for 2X2 it's 3437, for 3X2 it's 87084, and 6X2 is 2300. Individual Brick prices range from about £ .59 to £2.46 depending on design and colour. It took me over an hour to figure this out and buy some bricks. I hope this makes it a lot easier for anyone else. Happy Building!

Comment: Perfect! I used `6176` as the set number (an old discontinued set that had a lot of good bricks). No need to enter a part number, it will display all the parts in the set.

Comment: https://www.lego.com/en-us/service/replacementparts/sale/choose-brick

Answer (score 1):

Most of the time, best place to obtain LEGO bricks in any shape and colour is [Bricklink](https://bricklink.com).

Answer (score 0):

There are always "starter packs" with more of the simplest Duplo bricks available, at the time of the writing of this answer those are the sets #10848 (My First Bricks), #10572 (lego duplo all in one box of fun), and #10887 (Creative Fun).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what the equivalent in your country is, but I've had a lot of luck with Craigslist in the USA. When my daughter first got interested, I found a table with a TON of bricks for about $100, and I regularly see bulk DUPLO lots in the $30-80 range.

Answer (score 0):

I've had good luck at donation driven places such as The Goodwill, Salvation Army, and thrift stores.